# Adjective elemental or elementary?

Tags: difference

It seems *elementary* refers to rudiments and *elemental* to individual constituents, but there are also sentences like *elementary particles*, the individual constituents of atoms.

- How do English native speakers use them?

A rotation of an object in the 3D space can be described using a matrix, and can be decomposed into three individual 2D rotations.

- How would you refer to one particular operation in this chain of operations? Perhaps "*the 3D rotation is  made of three [elemental?] 2D rotations*".

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use either.  Can you provide a bit more context?  What kind of operations are you talking about?

Comment: If you are talking about maths, you need to say so!  Mathematicians have their own special language.

Comment: @JamesK: I'm not sure it should be looked at from a mathematics standpoint. Your answer is about something else. Rotation can be described by a matrix, but I'm talking about the composition of rotations, not the matrix reduction. I've a found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davenport_chained_rotations#Conversion_to_extrinsic_rotations): "*Any extrinsic rotation is equivalent to an intrinsic rotation by the same angles but with inverted order of **elemental rotations**, and vice versa*" which is about a chain of rotations, my exact case.

Comment: I think that is the Euler decompostion of a rotation matrix, but its been a long time since I 've done much of this kind of geometry.  Anyway  - this would be better asked on the maths StackExchange, since it is about a specialist term, not general English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *elemental* only to refer to spirits, in folklore or ancient relgiion.

In any other sense I would use *elementary*.

Comment: Is this incorrect or unusual: "*On the one hand, Systemic Functional Linguistics distinguishes **elemental genres** such as narrative, recount, arguments, exposition etc.*" [Source](https://www.ejmste.com/download/subject-specific-genres-and-genre-awareness-in-integrated-mathematics-and-language-teaching-5231.pdf), this is from a German university.

Comment: Well, I find it odd. The GlowBe corpus has only 2884 instances of _elemental_, against 18081 of _elementary_.

Comment: My own research also tends to show *elemental* is used in relation with *element* in the sense earth, wind, fire, water or iron, carbon, nitrogen, etc. Other uses seem to come from non native speakers.

Comment: @mins I was going to suggest the same; one might speak about "elemental carbon" (not part of a compound but simply pure carbon) but it is rarely used in other contexts